# How can I get a player to remember his character's bonuses?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, problem-players

In my *Dungeons & Dragons* group(s), we have a player who can never remember ability scores, spells, bonuses, etc. We currently have two groups, and he is in both. We enjoy playing with him, but it takes forever to find his stats. In our main campaign (7 sessions in), his character sheet is crumpled, only half-filled, etc. So my question is as follows:

**How can I get a player to remember his character's bonuses or at least make finding them take less time?**

Comment: Useful information you can add to get an answer: how well do you know the player? Is he engaged to the roleplaying part of the game? How does he behave during sessions?